# Configuring Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 E-mail Router forward mailbox in 3 environments

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We have 3 CRM environments (development, test, production) each with a separate e-mail router. I am trying to find out if it’s correct to have a separate e-mail router in each environment or is it better to have a single e-mail router processing e-mail for all 3 environments.  I am also wondering if it is correct to have a separate forward mailbox configured for each e-mail router i.e. crmdevmail, crmtestmail, crmprodmail.

We have 3 separate CRM environments (development, test, production) each configured with a separate e-mail router like the following:

Development
- CRMDBDev1
- CRMAPPDev1
- CRMAPPDev2
- CRMSRSDev1
- CRMMRDev1 <-- e-mail router in dev

Test
- CRMDBTest1
- CRMAPPTest1
- CRMAPPTest2
- CRMSRSTest1
- CRMMRTest1 <-- e-mail router in test

Production
- CRMDB1
- CRMAPP1
- CRMAPP2
- CRMSRS1
- CRMMR1 <-- e-mail router in prod

Each e-mail router is configured to process incoming e-mail from a separate forward mailbox.
- CRMMRDev1: crmdevmail@domain.org
- CRMMRTest1: crmtestmail@domain.org
- CRMMR1: crmprodmail@domain.org

**Question 1:** Is it typical to configure each CRM environment  (development, test, production) with a separate e-mail router?

**Question 2:** Is it better to have a single e-mail router processing e-mail for all 3 environments?

**Question 3:** What kind of issues may we run into by having a separate e-mail router in each CRM environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when developing CRM, one server is enough with different organizations on same server.

However, since you have more servers for CRM for each use (dev,test,prod), there should not be problem using seperated e-mail routers.

This is fine, but you should not use same email addresses between this dev,test,prod and everything will work fine.